# hide kendo grid refresh via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-grid

```
<a href="#" class="k-pager-refresh k-link" title="Refresh">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-refresh">Refresh</span>
</a>
```

I am trying to hide the span class using the following jquery code. However, there is no change, and the refresh icon keeps appearing.

```
$(".k-icon.k-i-refresh").css("display", "none");
```

I have also tried using

```
$(".k-icon.k-i-refresh").hide();
```

but it has no effecteither.

Comment: need more details.. where and when in your code are you trying to hide it? are there any errors in console?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan hiding the grid, after the grid is populated.

Comment: Can you show us the span's css?

Comment: @Tinsten I am pretty sure that is generated by KendoUI..

Comment: @KarthikGanesan yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Pageable` property of your grid you can set `refresh` to `false`. Like below:

```
pageable: {
    refresh: false,
    pageSizes: true,
    buttonCount: 5
}
```

Here is an example in a grid. Click [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/aPAgI) to see a running example.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
        },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 550,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: false,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 240
    }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title"
    }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
    }, {
        field: "Country",
        width: 150
    }]
});
```

This will remove the refresh button from the paging bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to disable button:

```
$(".k-pager-refresh").hide();
```

To disable only inner span class i have just tried (and it works):

```
$(".k-icon.k-i-reload").hide();
```

Make sure these lines is excecuted after grid creation. For example in $(document).ready block.